# amdgpu uninstall, mesa reinstall

Tags: drivers, 20.04, gpu, amdgpu, mesa

I recently installed the amdgpu-pro drivers for use with blender GPU render.
After the experiment I removed the driver (`with ./amdgpu-install --uninstall`).

After a reboot I could no longer log in correctly - after login I got an unspecific error message that "something went wrong".

So, knowing that sometimes there are issues with the mesa reinstall I first added the PPA of the stable mesa release.
However this did not change my situation.
After `ppa-purge` however I was able to log back in.

Now the interesting part begins:

I wanted to set my correct screen resolution, but could only set one (low) res.
Checking xrandr only showed one possible resolution.

Ok, maybe my gpu-driver was not loaded correctly.
Checking lshw -c video shows this: (sorry for German)

```
  *-display UNGEFORDERT     
       Beschreibung: VGA compatible controller
       Produkt: Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590]
       Hersteller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       Physische ID: 0
       Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:26:00.0
       Version: e7
       Breite: 64 bits
       Takt: 33MHz
       Fähigkeiten: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       Konfiguration: latency=0
       Ressourcen: memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f01fffff ioport:e000(Größe=256) memory:fe800000-fe83ffff memory:c00
```

See, there is no "driver = mesa". How can I enable the mesa driver?

I cant install the amdgpu-pro driver now, since it does not compile with the latest kernel.

Thanks everyone for reading through this.
I am contemplating a complete reinstall, but would really like to figure it out =)

Comment: I had a very similar problem and ended up doing a fresh re-install. I moved from 20.10 to 20.04.1 LTS hoping that the official graphics drivers would play nicer with the official LTS release. They don't. As of Feb 12, they still don't compile the dkms modules correctly. The scheduled driver update amd had for Feb 11 has been pushed back too. So I guess I'm just out of luck for now